# Can't get rid of minify after uninstalling W3 Total Cache

Tags: css, plugin-w3-total-cache

I've tried to replace my WP Super Cache for W3 Total Cache but it didn't worked. It was bugged all over and minify wouldn't work properly. So I uninstalled it s suggested by the plugin creator in one forum topic.

The problem is my CSS still seems to be cached. I edit my theme's default style.css and it still loads the old version no mater what I do. I've cleaned my cache for however many times. And even if you access the css file right from the browser it still gives you the old version (taking a look at it via FTP will show the right version).

What the hell is going on? To me it looks like minify is creeping somewhere in my WP installation and delivering the old cached CSS.

Could you guys point out where should I look?

EDIT

I've changed the theme folder name and the issue has gone, which kinda prove there's some minify remains messing up with my code.

I'd still like to get rid of it if someone can help

EDIT 2

So, this is seriously driving me nuts now.
Despite what I've said the issue persisted. So I've decided to DELET IT ALL and start from zero.

I've cleaned the database and the files. Installed a fresh WP install. Restored the database and only the uploads WP folder.

And guess what? The issue is still there. Is that an indication it's in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Look for a cache folder in the plug-in directory, wp-content directory or the themes directory and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

w3c does also add some stuff to your .htaccess file to encourage your browser to cache static files (such as stylesheets).  w/o the plugin activated it should not still be minifying.  there is a difference between minify and browser caching.  but check your .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

Here is [how to make CSS changes to go live immediately](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/force-css-changes-to-go-live-immediately/).